# WSO2 DSS appends timezone information to mysql date result

Tags: mysql, date, timezone, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

So I'm trying to use dates with mysql on the wso2 dss.
Simple code

```
<query id="testDates" useConfig="PORTFOLIOS_DS">
<sql>
  SELECT DATE(date) AS date FROM dateTest
</sql>
<result element="jsonObject" rowName="jsonArray">
  <element column="date" name="testDate" xsdType="date"/>
</result>
</query>
```

So it returns `"2015-03-10-04:00"` which isn't considered a valid date my many libraries (momentJS in particular) and to be fair it is a strange format, why do I care about timezone without the time.

Does anyone know why it is appending the timezone, how can I prevent the appending of timezone to dates but leave it on datetimes?

Comment: Had you solve this problem? I face same issue here.

Comment: I haven't properly. Short term we split the date apart on the ui with java script.  Long term we are replacing the dss with a nodejs most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue with DSS 3.5.0 version. So I have already created a public JIRA ticket [1]. and once this is fixed I will notify you.

In the meantime as a workaround, I would like to suggest to use an XSLT transformation to trip off timezone information. For more information about how to use XSLT inside the DSS server please refer [2]

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1191

[2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/XSLT+Transformation+Sample